# Pycharm - Waiting for REPL response when python console using IPython

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Response times in a PyCharm Python Console are unbearably slow when the console is configured to use IPython. This wasn't the case in a previous installation. When the Python Console is not configured to use IPython, and uses IDLE, it performs normally.

The poor response time seems to be linked to the REPL response function, as depicted in the image below. When the REPL response dialog completes, a background process continues to run for several minutes.

Since this was not a problem in a previous installation, the issue must be a result of a configuration change. However, the only thing I changed was to utilize a Conda env instead of a virtualenv.

Any ideas?

[image: Python Console]

Comment: Disable "Use IPython if available" temporally solve my problem.

Answer (score 12):

This issue was reported to JetBrains. The issue was duplicated and identified as a bug. The status of the issue can be viewed at:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24880

Comment: Thx for submitting that bug!

Comment: As today, same problem: I just typed `{'xx': 'yy'}.` then pressed `CTRL` - `Space` to open auto-completion...

Comment: Yep, this bug is **still** not resolved. This is outrageous.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to apply the "answer" found in the JetBrains bug filed by @vlmercado https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24880:

> Disable auto popup completions (in Editor->General->Code Completions)

[image]

Comment: my preferences didn't look exactly like that, but unchecking all the stuff worked.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. There was a particular option called "Machine Learning "Rank completion suggestions based on Machine Learning" disabling that has made everything run smoothly for now.

Answer (score 2):

Posting my comment as an answer, I have tried it now for a few days and had 0 `REPL` hangups.

`Ubuntu` but should work on every machine.

Go to: `File----> Settings---->Editor---->General---->Code Completion`

Uncheck `Rank completion suggestions based on Machine Learning`

That's it. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same problem in Pycharm2019.3 with Python3.8. It may have been caused by using miniconda instead of the full anaconda installation, because after installing the ipython package (with `-conda install ipython`) the long REPL waiting times have dissappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is solved by jetbrains, for me, it just randomly starts even after 1-2 hrs of coding,
I have tried every options found in Jet brains as well as Stack Overflow like checking and unchecking of 1,2 in combination as shown in image. Have experienced same with the code completion option as well,

These options might help:

Settings: File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console

Ipython Setting option:
[image: Ipython Setting option]
Run with Console option:
[image: Run with Console option]